# Angular2 Reactive Forms losing defaultValue when placed dynamically

Tags: jquery, angular

```
I am using the dynamic components created under this link using Reactiveforms in angular2.  All works well. When I an tying to place the dyanamic form-field component on specific locations on page using jquery `.html()` method , I am losing the default value of control 

https://github.com/mashhoodr/angular2-multicomponent-form


When I am trying to place the components dyanamcally on html to create a 2 column layout, like below , I am losing the defaultValue of controls.  

Here's the code of my html :

    <form [formGroup]="step" >
           <div id="box-{{stepName}}"> </div>


            <!-- rendering the fields dynamically -->
            <div *ngFor="let fieldName of getFieldsList() let i = index" id="datadiv-{{fieldName}}" style="display: none">
              <form-field [field]="fm.getField(fieldName)" [count]="i"  [editMode]="editMode"  ></form-field>
            </div>
        </form>     
export class ABCComponent {

constructor(){}

    ngAfterViewInit(){



    let mytable = $('<table width="100%" style="margin-top:15px" ></table>').attr({ id: "tbl-"+this.stepName });

        var tr = [];
      var col_counter: number = 0;
      //for (var i = 0; i < Object.keys(this.step['controls']).length/2; i++) {

            var row = $('<tr></tr>').attr({ class: ["ui", "dividing", "header"].join(' ') }).appendTo(mytable);

         Object.keys(this.step['controls']).map((key)=>{ 
            $('<td width="50%"></td>').attr({id: key}).appendTo(row); 

          if(col_counter>=Object.keys(this.step['controls']).length-1) //Last row only needs to be closed.
          {
            row = $('</tr>').appendTo(mytable);
          }
          else if(col_counter%2==1 )
          { 
            row = $('<tr></tr>').attr({ class: ["ui", "dividing", "header"].join(' ') }).appendTo(mytable);

          }
          col_counter++;
        });


        //};

    //  console.log("TTTTT:"+mytable.html());
      mytable.appendTo("#box-"+this.stepName);

     Object.keys(this.step['controls']).map((key)=>{ 

        $("#"+key).html($("#datadiv-"+key).html());
      }

      });
    }

}
```

This is the Service class which is fetching the metadata and the data value from the http service. The binding are working fine but not sure what i am missing when I try to place the controls in 2 column layout using jquery

```
@Injectable()
export class FormFieldService {

 private metadata : Object;
 private loan : ILoan;

  panels: Array<PanelFields> = new Array();


  constructor(private cache: CacheManager){}

  getPanels(objKey?:string, objId?:string) :Array<PanelFields> {

     this.metadata = this.cache.get(objKey);
     if(this.metadata==null) throw 'MetaData for '+objKey+' not loaded.'

     this.loan = this.cache.get(objId);

     if(this.loan==null) throw 'Object Data for '+objId+' not loaded.'
    return  this.getFormFields(this.metadata, this.loan);
   }

getFormFields(metadata :Object, loan: ILoan) :Array<PanelFields> {

   let fields : Array<FormField>;
   Object.keys(metadata).map((key)=>{ 
      let pf : PanelFields = new PanelFields();
      pf.name = key;

    let objArr = metadata[key];
     fields= new Array();
    objArr.map( (meta: IObjectMetaData)=> { 

      if(meta.fieldType=='STRING')
      {
          let tf: TextFormField = new TextFormField({ 
          name: meta.name, 
          label: meta.label, 
          **defaultValue: loan[meta.name],**
          required: meta.isRequired,
          inlineHelp: meta.inlineHelpText,
          placeholder: loan[meta.name]

        })
        fields.push(tf);
      }
      else
      {
        if(meta.fieldType=='NUMBER')
        {
          let tf: NumberFormField = new NumberFormField({ 
          name: meta.name, 
          label: meta.label, 
          **defaultValue: loan[meta.name],**
          required: meta.isRequired,
          inlineHelp: meta.inlineHelpText,
          placeholder: loan[meta.name]

        })
          fields.push(tf);
        }
      }
   });//map
    pf.fields = fields;
    this.panels.push(pf);
 });//keys

 return this.panels;
}
}
```

Comment: How did you bind dynamic control input values?

Comment: Seems a bit weird to me that you use value binding together with reactive forms

Comment: As mentioned in the above link, instead of hardcoding the metadata (eg name of field) and value , I am fetching it from server using https service. In the code below, meta data is binding correctly and default value is also binding correctly but the moment I try to place the control in 2 column using jquery, ,default value does not show up on the textbox. Though I can still see it and place it on label. I have added the service code on my question.   @Günter Zöchbauer : What exactly you find weird ?

Comment: Please create plunker that reproduces your problem

Comment: I created the below plunk with the issue but facing an error wherein it's not able to find my component. Can you please help resolve this issue. I have never used plunk before and still learning angular.
https://plnkr.co/edit/kR6SoHsF11gkCggKS16H

Answer (score 0):

I fixed the issue. It seems the Jquery.html() function is not respecting the FormControl property of reactiveforms.  So,instead of using html() i bind the node directly . That works for me.

$("#"+key).replaceWith($("#datadiv-"+key)[0]);